# Vw Golf-5 can't turn the ignition, brake pedal stiff and key broken

Tags: vw, golf

My VW golf-5 does not turn the ignition on, radio turns on together with the light and no dim lights. The brake pedal is stone hard, tried wriggling the steering wheel left and right while at the same time turning the key but it cannot start or turn the display box on.

I just broke the key and now using a spare but the problem persists.

The key mobilizer is working just fine and the battery is fully charged.

Comment: The brake pedal being rock hard is not abnormal if you've applied and released the brakes a few times without the car running. You will have used up all the leftover vacuum, and the brake booster will no longer be helping you apply the brakes.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to turn the key so hard it breaks.  Most newer vehicles will lock the steering wheel if you turn the wheels without the key in the ignition.

Basically, keep doing what you initially tried but don't turn the key so hard.  Just keep jiggling the steering wheel back and forth, pump the brakes a few times and gently turn the key.  This unlocks the steering wheel on most vehicles.

If that isn't working, check your owner's manual.  It should mention how to unlock the steering wheel in there.

UPDATE:

According to [this link](http://volkswagenownersclub.com/vw/showthread.php/3832-Steering-Wheel-Stuck-Car-Won-t-Start) you may have to put some oomph into jiggling the steering wheel, but still go gentle on the key. You don't want to break the key off in the ignition.